# An expression to work out the average time from a single dataset field SSRS

Tags: function, datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I am have trouble with this relatively simple question. I need to use an expression that works out the `AVG` time of a dataset field. So I have a list of resolution times (a calculated field called `Field!Resolution_Time.Value`)

I basically want to work out an average of all the response times in this field.

Ive tried this;

```
=Avg(Fields!Resolution_Time.Value)
```

but this doesn't seem to work, it just outputs a float. And there is no function to convert floats into time values. Any ideas?

There's no real definitive answer to this online which is quite surprising as I would have thought such a question would be quite common.

Comment: It's unclear to me how to reproduce your scenario, most specifically the data type of the column in your query and the SSRS field data type. Could you help us create a minimal repro from scratch by including steps to do so in your question?

Comment: =Avg(Fields!Resolution_Time.Value,"DataSetName") use this expression. Hope It will work for you issue.

Comment: Which data type you use to store resolution time in database?

Comment: The datatype of the field Resolution_Time is a calculated field of 2 other date/time fields. so I have (date/time field 1 - date/time field 2) = Resolution_time. When trying the example you have given for some reason just outputs -HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

You can't use function `avg` with `Timespan` datatype, so you should get number of seconds of your `resolution_time`. And then you get it average value.

For example, if data type of `resolution_type` is `Time`, you can use this expression:
`=Avg(Fields!resolution_time.Value.TotalSeconds, "DataSet1")`

Comment: The datatype of the field Resolution_Time is a calculated field of 2 other date/time fields. so I have (date/time field 1 - date/time field 2) = Resolution_time. When trying the example you have given for some reason just outputs -HH:mm:ss

Comment: also to add some extra detail, the Resolution_Time comes out as days:hours:minutes:seconds (eg. 10:12:24:56 )format in report. Also not all cells are filled (ones that do not have any data in time/date field 1 or in date/time field 2 for example)